# Joining elements of a list in GNU Make

Tags: makefile

In my makefile I have a variable with a list of directories, like this:

```
DIRS = /usr /usr/share/ /lib
```

Now, I need to create PATH variable from it, which is basically the same, but uses semicolon as a separator:

```
PATH = /usr:/usr/share/:/lib
```

How do I do that? I mean, how do I join elements of DIRS list with semicolons, instead of spaces?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571658/gnu-make-convert-spaces-to-colons

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use the `$(subst)` command, combined with a little trick to get a variable that has a value of a single space:

```
p = /usr /usr/share /lib
noop=
space = $(noop) $(noop)

all:
        @echo $(subst $(space),:,$(p))
```

Comment: You also can use `$(eval)` instead of `$(noop)` there, thus eliminating the need for defining noop.

Comment: Seem like a black magic, but described in [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Syntax-of-Functions)

Comment: Actually, changed my mind. I think Dave's $(eval) solution is better. It avoids polluting the variable name space not only with $(noop) but also $(space).

Answer (score 16):

Cleanest Form (that I can find):

```
classpathify = $(subst $(eval ) ,:,$(wildcard $1))
cp = a b c d/*.jar

target:
    echo $(call classpathify,$(cp))
# prints a:b:c:d/1.jar:d/2.jar
```

Notes:

- Turning it into a pseudo-function makes the intention clearer than doing a bunch of arcane string manipulation inline.
- Note the trailing space after `eval`: `$(eval )`. Without this, make interprets `$(eval)` as a variable rather than calling the `eval` function. If the trailing space is omitted, you could replace `eval` with `some_undefined_variable` and the text replacement will still happen. However, if you run make with the `--warn-undefined-variable` flag, you'll get a warning that `eval` or `some_undefined_variable` is undefined.
- I included the $(wildcard) function because you almost always use these two together when specifying a classpath
- Make sure not to put any extra spaces in after the commas or you will get something like "::a:b:c:d:e".

Comment: One thing I'd add: Now that java supports the "-cp lib/*" syntax, you can avoid doing the $(wildcard $1), which is probably a good thing to do as the tendency for Java projects to use a ton of JAR's can lead to cases where you exceed length limits on certain platforms.

Comment: A more generic form:
joinwith = $(subst $(eval) ,$1,$2)
$(call joinwith, -o , $(list_of_files_separated_by_spaces))

Answer (score 3):

You use ':' as separator, so you are on Linux. Consider using bash tool chain to replace continuous spaces by single colon

```
PATH := $(shell echo $(DIRS) | sed "s/ \+/:/g")
```