# GNU Make Convert Spaces to Colons

Tags: makefile, path, gnu-make, space

Given a colon-delimited list of paths, getting a space-delimited list with *GNU Make* is straightforward:

```
CPATHS := /usr/bin/foo:/usr/bin/baz:/usr/bin/baz
SPATHS := $(subst :, ,$(CPATHS))
```

However, I couldn't find a nice way to go the opposite direction.  The following hack does work (at least if *sed* is installed) but I'm pretty sure there will be a nicer way to solve this just using *Make*'s internal functions.

```
SPATHS := /usr/bin/foo /usr/bin/baz /usr/bin/baz
CPATHS := $(shell echo $(SPATHS) > tmp; sed 's/ \+/:/g' tmp; rm tmp)
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The only tricky part here is to define a literal space:

```
space := $(subst ,, )

SPATHS := /usr/bin/foo /usr/bin/baz /usr/bin/baz
CPATHS := $(subst $(space),:,$(SPATHS))
```

Comment: I prefer to use `empty :=` then `space := $(empty) $(empty)`.  Just a bit more clear and doesn't rely on a side-effect.  But both will work.

Comment: Cool, thanks.  I think I will use `SPACE := $(eval) $(eval)` to get a space token.  I was thinking that `subst` operates on the words individually and therefore doesn't see the spaces between them.

Comment: Another option is to use `space := $(subst ,, )`.

Comment: The best answer is:
SPACE := $() $()
because it works on every version of make and takes only one line :).
Your answer works well on make 4.2.x, but it doesn't work on make 4.3:

* WARNING: Backward-incompatibility!
  Previously appending using '+=' to an empty variable would result in a value
  starting with a space.  Now the initial space is only added if the variable
  already contains some value.  Similarly, appending an empty string does not
  add a trailing space.

Comment: @jakson thank you, I didn't know that. I updated the answer to use `$(subst ,, )`. While your snippet works too, I suspect it can cause warnings when `make` is launched with `--warn-undefined-variables`.

Comment: @EldarAbusalimov, you right about warnings, so the only one-line answer is yours (subst-way). PS MadScientist answer works without warnings (define empty).

Answer (score 23):

The shortest way to get a literal space would be via `$() $()`. Thus:

```
$(subst $() $(),:,$(CPATHS))
```

Or, for brevity:

```
_=$() $()
$(subst $(_),:,$(CPATHS))
```

It is perhaps an interesting curiosity that the same trick works with cmake's macros, i.e. that `${}` is a separator but introduces no whitespace by itself.

Comment: You don't need the second `$()`. `$(subst $() ,:,$(CPATHS))` works. The `subst` function doesn't trim whitespace from its arguments, so all you really need to do is to force `make` to stop eating whitespace after it scans the function name.

Comment: @MattWhitlock Good to know! That probably goes for Cmake too - I have to check!